# Prevent CodeMirror AutoResize (react-codemirror2)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, codemirror

I am creating a code editor using react-codemirror2. I have the editor in a flexbox and I only want the codemirror editor to take up 100% of the remaining space in the parent div (which also contains a button and another div). The problem is once I set .CodeMirror to 100%, it becomes the height that I want it to be, but when I add enough lines, it does not scroll (like I want it to, but rather it extends beyond its container (autoresizing). I do not want this autoresize.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you try to recreate the issue in a jsfiddle and add it to your question?

Comment: I fixed this by adding `height: 0%` to parent container (if editor was expanding the parent vertically) or `width: 0%` to parent container (if editor was expanding the parent horizontally). Definitely a weird flexbox quirk of CodeMirror